# Global variable arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, global-variables, arduino-uno, i2c

I'm using I2C to communicate a Master Arduino to 4 Slaves Arduinos, and an Shield (OULIMEX Shield LCD 16x2) on every Arduino slave.
I send Data from the master to slaves using I2C. So I use this code in the master :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <floatToString.h>

double incomingData;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  incomingData = Serial.parseFloat();    //read incoming data
}

void loop()
{
  delay (1000);

  if (Serial.available())
  {

    incomingData = Serial.parseFloat(); //read incoming data
    Wire.beginTransmission(8);    // transmit to device #8 



    if ((M==0) || (M==1) || (M==2))
      Wire.beginTransmission(8);    // transmit to device #8 *****************************************************************

    else
      Wire.beginTransmission(7);    // transmit to device #7 *****************************************************************     
    M++;
    if (M==5)
      M=0;

    String a = ""; 
    a = floatToString(test,incomingData,3,5,true);
    for(i=0; a[i]!='\0'; ++i);    // length of the string

    Wire.write(i);
    Wire.write(floatToString(test,incomingData,3,5,true));      //  sends one byte
    Wire.endTransmission();    //    stop transmitting
    }

}
```

I wanted the Data to be printed on the Shield, but I'm connecting all slaves with the same way with the master. For that I have two problems :

1- The global data I'm using to print value is always printed as 0, and not giving the real value;

2- All Shields print the same thing : For exemple, I print "hello" in the first Shield, and I print "hi" in the second Shield, but bouth are printing the same thing (hello or hi).

The code using for the first slave is :

```
#include <LCD16x2.h>
#include <Wire.h>

LCD16x2 lcd;

int buttons;

int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

float numOut;
int comp=1 ;
String wordd = "";
int M =0;

void setup()
{

  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output  

}

void loop()
{
 delay(500);
}   
 // function that executes whenever data is received from master
 // this function is registered as an event, see setup()
  void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  wordd = "";
  int x = Wire.read();
  for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
  {
    char c = Wire.read();
    wordd += c;
  }
  numOut = wordd.toFloat();
  Serial.println(numOut,3);         // print the integer
}
```

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already ask this question but I think I have the answer of it. A global variable have to be diclared befor the void setup, and the void loop too, like that :

```
type YourGlobalVariable;

void setup()
{
}
void loop()
{
}
```

So, it is exactly how I did already. The reason it didn't work for me, it was cause of I used this function :

```
  void receiveEvent(int howMany) {}
```

I don't really know what are the properties of it that let it not work for a global variables, but It works like I sayd already.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to a poor program structure in master shield.

This block selects the slave but on the first line you already select #8
I think this is confusing for the slaves.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(8);    // transmit to device #8 

    if ((M==0) || (M==1) || (M==2))
      Wire.beginTransmission(8);    // transmit to device #8 
    else
      Wire.beginTransmission(7);    // transmit to device #7
```

This block should be at the end of the function

```
M++;
if (M==5)
  M=0;
```

Then you parse the value in a string.
But leave out the first char because you write ++i instead of i++

Moreover you close the loop with ; so it does nothing

```
String a = ""; 
a = floatToString(test,incomingData,3,5,true);
for(i=0; a[i]!='\0'; ++i);    // length of the string
```

Finally you write the ordinal number of the byte
And then again the Whole string

So you should get "0" (or "1" because of ++i)
followed by your number if Wire.write() supports it

```
Wire.write(i);
Wire.write(floatToString(test,incomingData,3,5,true));      //  sends one byte
Wire.endTransmission();    //    stop transmitting
}
```

Your sketch should be:

```
if (Serial.available())
    {
    incomingData = Serial.parseFloat(); //read incoming data

    String a = ""; 
    a = floatToString(test,incomingData,3,5,true);

    if ((M==0) || (M==1) || (M==2))
        Wire.beginTransmission(8);    // transmit to device #8 
    else
        Wire.beginTransmission(7);    // transmit to device #7 

    for(i=0; a[i]!='\0'; ++i)    // length of the string
        Wire.write(a[i]);        // write one byte


    Wire.endTransmission();    //    stop transmitting

    M++;
    if (M==5) M=0;
    }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the details. you are right I put a line more `Wire.beginTransmission(8);`.
However, the program is working perfectly and send the Data from the Master to the Slave, I'm printing Data on the Slave to Matlab (using Serial port) and it appears correct. For that I think that there isn't a problem in my code writing on the master, but it is **only** when I try to print it on the LCD that it cause a problem.
I'm sending the length of the String `Wire.write(i);` to concatinate it in the Slave `int x = Wire.read();`.
Thank you for any other suggestion or a question